# postgresql syntax error using DAY as date

Tags: postgresql

I can't identify the syntax mistake on this query, where´s the syntax mistake?

```
SELECT A.WPAN8, A.WPSRP1, A.WPBP01, A.WPSLSM, A.WP55QTA1, A.WPCENTYR, 
A.WPAAN01, A.WPAAN02, A.WPAAN03, A.WPAAN04, A.WPAAN05, A.WPAAN06, 
A.WPAAN07, A.WPAAN08, A.WPAAN09, A.WPAAN10, A.WPAAN11, A.WPAAN12, 
cast(((((((cast(cast(((WPUPMJ / 1000) + 1900) as decimal (4,0)) as 
char(4)) || '-01-01 ') || substring(cast(cast((WPUPMT + 1000000) as 
decimal (7,0)) as char(7)) from 2 for 2)) || ':') || 
substring(cast(cast((WPUPMT + 1000000) as decimal (7,0)) as char(7)) from 
4 for 2)) || ':') || substring(cast(cast((WPUPMT + 1000000) as decimal 
(7,0)) as char(7)) from 6 for 2)) as timestamp)+ 
ceiling(cast(substring(cast(cast(((WPUPMJ + 1900000) - 1) as decimal (7)) 
as character (7)) from 5 for 3) as decimal (3)))DAY as maxdate FROM 
CRPDTA.F5742001 A where cast(((((((cast(cast(((WPUPMJ / 1000) + 1900) as 
decimal (4,0)) as char(4)) || '-01-01 ') || substring(cast(cast((WPUPMT + 
1000000) as decimal (7,0)) as char(7)) from 2 for 2)) || ':') || 
substring(cast(cast((WPUPMT + 1000000) as decimal (7,0)) as char(7)) from 
4 for 2)) || ':') || substring(cast(cast((WPUPMT + 1000000) as decimal 
(7,0)) as char(7)) from 6 for 2)) as timestamp)+ 
ceiling(cast(substring(cast(cast(((WPUPMJ + 1900000) - 1) as decimal (7)) 
as character (7)) from 5 for 3) as decimal (3)))DAY > '2000-01-01 
00:00:00.000000';
```

It is saying ERROR: syntax error at or near "DAY"

Comment: seriously, why are you re-inventing `to_timestamp`  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

postgresql uses a slightly different interval syntax to that.

I think you want `* '1 day'::interval` instead of `DAY`

Comment: Yes Jasen,I want it to one day

Comment: replace every ocurrance of `DAY` in your query with `* '1 day'::interval` and it should work (may need more parentheses), but look at  `to_timestamp` which probably provides a much much simpler way to write that query.